# Disabling/enabling parts of the import wizard in Eclipse RCP application in certain situations

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have added a new entry in the import wizard and it works fine. My goal, however, is to enable the "special type" of importing **only** when an entry in the system explorer has been selected and right-clicked on. For any other way (e.g. File -> Import...) I don't want to have the newly added option.

I have gone through the documentation and something like `activeWhen`, `enableWhen` or even `with` tag seem to look like something I could use, but I saw them in the context of commands and not wizards.

Comment: The import wizard only looks the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point for things to leave out - which I don't think can do what you want. What do you mean by "system explorer" - one of the Eclipse explorer views, or the OS explorer?

Comment: The system explorer refers to one of the Eclipse views, sorry for the lack of context. I also haven't found anything else yet, it might not be possible to do what I want (at least now).

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should just contribute a menu item to the right click menu of Package/Project Explorer.

Comment: I was thinking the same but the requirement in the end is to put it in the Import wizard, unfortunately.

Comment: Well that is not how Import is supposed to work. import wizards are given the current selection if there is one but they are supposed to provide a way to choose something if there is no selection or the selection is not suitable.

Comment: @greg-449 I have managed to solve it, you can see the answer below (if you're interested).

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that it's possible to hide/disable certain wizards depending on the selection. The answer [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=160373&goto=507518&#msg_507518) really helped, as it's explained step-by-step. I combined the previous link with [this](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_expressions.htm) for my solution. I wanted to show 2 wizards only when there is one element selected and when it's of a certain type (and for the 1st wizard, when it's of a certain name).

The resulting solution is something like this:

```
<activity
        name="Some Activity"
        description="Activity for ..."
        id="unique.id.that.you.give.to.the.activity">
        <enabledWhen>
            <and>
                <count value="1"/>
                <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                    <or>
                        <and>
                            <instanceof value="some.Type1"/>
                            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                                value="SomeName"/>
                        </and>
                        <instanceof value="some.Type2"/>
                    </or>
                </iterate>
            </and>
        </enabledWhen>
    </activity>
    <activityPatternBinding 
        activityId="unique.id.that.you.give.to.the.activity" 
        pattern=".*/id.of.the.first.wizard.i.wanted.to.disable">
    </activityPatternBinding>
    <activityPatternBinding 
        activityId="unique.id.that.you.give.to.the.activity" 
        pattern=".*/id.of.the.second.wizard.i.wanted.to.disable">
    </activityPatternBinding>
```